# Excel formula to combine text from multiple cells

Tags: excel-formula

I have to combine text from multiple cells into one cell. The cells are date and time. Does anyone know how to write an excel formula to combine the text for D2, D5, D8 and so on? Thanks

Excel sheet example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
=CONCAT(C1," ",TEXT(A1,"HH:MM:ss")," ",B1)
```

C1 contains your date(Example 11/24/2021), A1 is your time(10:40:40) and B1 is your AM/PM.

Comment: Thanks Anupam. You formula will have an output after I modified as =CONCATENATE(TEXT(C1,"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")&" "&B1)

Comment: CONCAT is the preferred function as of 2016. CONCATENATE is still available for backwards compatibility or if you have an old version of Office. In this case however, you could just leave off the function entirely:
=TEXT(C1,"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")&" "&B1